# Extra 16 bytes generated by C# AES encryption

Tags: c#, encryption, aes

I am using the following code to test the C# AES encryption and the output is 32 bytes instead of 16. I'd like to understand what is the extra 16 bytes. Thank you very much for any help.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.IO.Compression;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text;

namespace TestEnc
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            byte[] key = { 50, 41, 132,234,143,17,
                       89, 74,   2, 56, 36,87,
                       54, 87,  88, 28};

            byte[] iv = { 45, 241,153,24,14,17,
                       8, 57,32,5,96,47,
                       54,87,88,8};
            using (Rijndael algorithm = Rijndael.Create())
            {
                algorithm.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
                using (ICryptoTransform encryptor = algorithm.CreateEncryptor(key, iv))
                {
                    string fullpath = @"c:\test.txt";
                    using (Stream FileOutStream = File.Open(fullpath, FileMode.Create))
                    {
                        using (Stream encStream = new CryptoStream(FileOutStream, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                        {
                            string s = "hello world 1234";
                            for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
                            {
                                encStream.Write(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(s), 0, (int)s.Length);
                            }
                        }

                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/12621/why-does-openssl-append-extra-bytes-when-encrypting-with-aes-128-ecb answer your question?

Comment: [`algorithm.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padding_(cryptography)#PKCS%235_and_PKCS%237)

Comment: [PKCS7 padding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padding_(cryptography)#PKCS#5_and_PKCS#7) pads up to the nearest 16-byte boundary, *except* when your plaintext's length is a multiple of 16, when it adds 16 bytes of padding. "hello world 1234" (in ASCII) is 16 bytes long, so you're getting an additional 16 bytes of padding.

Comment: Also, **DO NOT** use a constant IV. Your IV needs to have a different unpredictable value every time you encrypt something. Use a secure random number (`RNGCryptoServiceProvider`): it's common to write the IV as the first few bytes of the ciphertext, so the decryption side can retrieve them

Comment: @canton7 : Thank you very much. PKCS7 padding appears to be the reason. But why it adds another 16 bytes when the length is a multiple of 16?

Comment: @leon Read the linked Wikipedia page on PKCS7. Basically, if it added no padding in this case, when it came to remove the padding, it might not be able to successfully tell that no padding was added (what if the message naturally ended with `01` or `02 02`?)